# How to have a application (C program) for .ko program Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel

I have:

1. A C program `main.c` with the main function that has the function call.
2. Another C program `test.c` with function definitions.
3. A header `test.h` has the common declarations.

**Pls read Carefully my objective**
my objective is to have a kernel object and a appliction that uses it.
and i need to give some inputs to the function at runtime and process with that.

i'm using it in terminal. 
Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: What does this have to do with `linux-kernel`, `embedded-linux` or `kernel-programming`?

Comment: @nightcracker: To the extent that a `.ko` file is a Linux kernel module, there is apparently something to do with Linux kernel (or a closely related tag).  I'm not sure whether the requirement to use a kernel module is sensible; I suspect there should be a homework tag attached to the question.

Comment: Could you please explain your goal? In fact, .ko is the kernel level entity while main() is intended for application level. The way it can be used - is insmod to install .ko and then use ioctl() to use driver interface.

Comment: Maybe RTFM: http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Module-HOWTO/x839.html http://www.linuxchix.org/content/courses/kernel_hacking/lesson8

Comment: Does the original poster know about `dlopen` and `dlsym` using the `-ldl` library?

Comment: I think in this case, a simple dynamic link should do the work, but **dlopen** and **dlsym** are good to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compiling kernel module, you can write this basic makefile :

```
obj-m += <your_obj_file>.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

After that, you'll have to build and load your module with

```
make
insmod <your_module>.ko
```

But when I read you, I guess that what you really want to do is not a kernel module.
I think you want to build a shared library (**.so** file or **.dll**), isn't it ?

If it's a linux shared library you want to build here's the commands to invoke :

```
gcc -c -fPIC test.c
gcc -shared test.o -o libtest.so

gcc -c main.c
gcc main.o -o <binary name> -ltest
```

But if you just want to build a static binary in the classical way :

```
gcc -c test.c
gcc -c main.c

gcc test.o main.o -o <binary name>
```